# OVH IP Failover configuration on Webmin-Virtualmin

Tags: centos, centos7, virtualmin

After a ddos attack i changed my server to a better one and I phurcased also an IP Failover for the first time. So, in ovh manager everything is right but Im using virtualmin and I have never did this job before.

In Webmin > Networking > Network Intefaces

I have eth0 with the actual server IP which is shared on two nameservers ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com

I have also eth1 which one is not editable or clickable with an information which tells in red color "down"

Im using centos 7 and the server currently is active with 5 sites.

How can I activate on webmin the sedond IP failover?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your fail over ip on public interfaces, in your case eth0, so you need to create eth0:0 with your failover ip

```
under the webmin tab go to Networking - Network Configuration
Then go to Network Interfaces and add a new interface (virtual or physical) with assigned IP.
```

Comment: thankyou but how about the default IP if I edit eth0 it will get the new IP instead of default server ip and Im afraid of any incident which can break everything.The sites are up and all these sites are active ecommerce sites.

Comment: @Gazi you need to add an virtual interface eth0:0 and then you can configure the ip on eth0:0